# How do I manually install the necessary packages to get TeXmaker to work? And in which directory do I put them?

Tags: packages, texmaker, ubuntu

I use Ubuntu 12.04 and I'm just getting started with TeXmaker. However, I need to get the library/package (what's the difference anyway?) for it to work and I'm having trouble with finding it in the Ubuntu software manager. I have thought of installing them manually, but again I think I would have to put them in the right directories, right? I'm really not an expert in informatics, I just need to do some serious physics writing for my thesis so I guess I would need the maths/physics packages. Also the French package would be of great help.

Comment: See here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1092/how-to-install-vanilla-texlive-on-debian-or-ubuntu do never ever use the Ubuntu repositories for any tex-distribution.